# how to set random color on a button in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-button, material-components-android

i am trying to make button which changes color when is pressed.
i have tried to use

```kotlin
button!!.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList(
    arrayOf(intArrayOf(R.dimen.padding_large))
    intArrayOf(panit!!color)
)
```

and

```kotlin
button!!.setBacgroundColor(paint!!.color)
```

but button becomes like that in 100% of situations, even through `paint.color` is a random number each time
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1st parameter of [`ColorStateList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList) is an array of states.

You have to use something like:

```
    val colorList = ColorStateList(
        arrayOf(
            intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_pressed),  // Pressed
            intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_enabled),  // Enabled
            intArrayOf()
        ),
        intArrayOf(
            Color.BLUE,      // The color for the Pressed state
            Color.BLACK,     // The color for the Enabled state
            Color.RED        // The color for the Disabled state
        )
    )

    button.backgroundTintList = colorList
```

Comment: sorrily it does not help

Comment: @bruh what is the issue? I've just tried the code and it works

Comment: well i copied it the same as you wrote it and it works now. i guewss just a missclick. thanks for solution